# Setting difficulty level for my simple game

Tags: java, user-interface, methods

I have been coding a simple grid pirate game, I want the player to be presented with a screen that has two buttons on it labelled easy and hard. Depending on which button they press it will close that screen down and bring up a new window with different sized grids. At the moment the code is written for a three by three grid which I want to set as the hard and want to code a two by two for easy. What I am having trouble with is declaring new methods to put another gui in, separate to the one that I already have. Any suggestions/solutions would be greatly appreciated?

```
  import java.awt.*;
  import javax.swing.*;
  import javax.swing.Timer;
 import java.util.*; 
 import java.awt.event.*;





  public class PirateGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

  JLabel label1, label2, label3;

  ImageIcon image1, image2, image3, image4, image5; 

  JTextField textResult; 

  JButton [] buttons;


  int treasureLocation; 

  int clicks = 0;

 public int count = 0;       


 public static void main(String[] args){


  new PirateGame();

  }


   public PirateGame (){




  this.setSize(700,700);
  this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.setTitle("Treasure Hunt Game");

  JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();


  thePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3,0,0));

  image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Treasure.jpg"));
  image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Pirate.jpg"));
  image3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("sand2.jpg"));
  image4 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("emptyhole.jpg"));   
  image5 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("map.jpg"));

  label1 = new JLabel("Click the buttons!");
  label1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
  label1.setForeground(Color.red);


  label2 = new JLabel(image5); 
  label3 = new JLabel(image2);


  buttons = new JButton[9]; 
  buttons[0] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[1] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[2] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[3] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[4] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[5] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[6] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[7] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[8] = new JButton(image3);





  thePanel.add(buttons[0]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[1]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[2]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[3]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[4]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[5]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[6]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[7]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[8]);
  thePanel.add(label1); 
  thePanel.add(label2);
  thePanel.add(label3);

  buttons[0].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[1].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[2].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[3].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[4].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[5].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[6].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[7].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[8].addActionListener(this);



  this.add(thePanel);

  this.setVisible(true);



  treasureLocation = new Random().nextInt(buttons.length);


  System.out.println(treasureLocation);




   }




   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
   Object source = evt.getSource();

  if (source == buttons[treasureLocation]) {


     buttons[treasureLocation].setIcon(image1);
     label1.setText("You've found me Treasure!");

     Timer timer = new Timer(3000,  
           new ActionListener() {


              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 

                 PirateGame.this.setVisible(false);
                 PirateGame.this.dispose();
                 new PirateGame();

              }
           }); 
     timer.setRepeats(false); 
     timer.start();
   }
   else
   {((JButton)source).setIcon(image4); 
     label1.setText("Keep tryin' ARGG!");

   }


   clicks++;
   System.out.println(clicks);


   if ((clicks == 5) && (source !=  buttons[treasureLocation])){

     label1.setText("One more try Matey!");

   }

   if ((clicks == 6) && (source !=  buttons[treasureLocation])) {

     label1.setText("Walk the Plank!");


     Timer timer2 = new Timer(3000,  
           new ActionListener() {


              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 

                 PirateGame.this.setVisible(false);
                 PirateGame.this.dispose();
                 new PirateGame();

              }
           }); 
     timer2.setRepeats(false); 
     timer2.start();
   }

   if (clicks == 7){

     PirateGame.this.setVisible(false);
     PirateGame.this.dispose();
     new PirateGame();
   }

  }  





 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for starters - move all of your ui creation code to a separate method

CreateUI( int GridSize )

use for loops to create your buttons etc.

```
int numButtons = GridSize * GridSize;
buttons = new JButton[Grid]; 
for ( int i = 0; i < numButtons; i++ )
{
 buttons[i] = new JButton(image3);
}
```

For starter's get your UI working so you can pass it 2 or 3, and just change the code manually and test that both work.

Then you have to learn about how to switch the UI while you are running.  My guess
is that for your code:

```
  this.add(thePanel);

  this.setVisible(true);
```

You need to figure out how to remove thePanel, make a new one and add it.  Those are some ideas for a start...